# Flow Proof for Proving Parallelogram $ABHF$

Tags: geometry

If $ACDH$ is a parallelogram, $B$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AC}$, and $F$ is the midpoint of $\overline{HD}$, write a flow proof to prove that $ABFH$ is also a parallelogram.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB||HF$ and $AB=HF \Rightarrow ABHF -$ parallelogram

Answer (score 1):

When the segments are vectors:

$AC||DH ,\; AH|| CD $  hence $ ACDH is a parallelogram (given)

Half of one vector pair are also parallel

$ (AC/2)\, ||\, (DH/2)  $

or

$ AB\, ||\, HF  $

Also

length of parallel vectors is equal by given construction.

$ \overline{AB}= \overline {HF },$ hence $ ABFH $ is a parallelogram.